# Why isn't this for loop properly searching through my data set and instead of showing elements, shows none?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

So, im relatively new to coding, taking a csp class and wanting to do stuff outside of it like this, so i dont know a *ton*, but I feel I know a little bit, so I apologize if this code is such a "Holy crap this is a horrible mess" piece of code, but i tried. No matter how may times ive tried to fix this, for some reason nothing works and I can never get the proper elements to show, as it keeps returning false at the first if statement no matter what. Dont worry about updateSeaerchBar(), the code doesnt even get to it in the first place.

```
onEvent("friendSearchBar","input",function(){
  var temp;
  userS = getColumn("User's Data","name");
  possiblePeople = 0;
  hideElement("friendOption1");
  hideElement("friendOption2");
  hideElement("friendOption3");
  hideElement("friendOption4");
  hideElement("friendOption5");
  search = getText("friendSearchBar");
  storedWord = "";
  potential1 = "";
  potential2 = "";
  potential3 = "";
  potential4 = "";
  potential5 = "";
  for(var n = 0;n<=userS.length-1;n++){
    for(var h = 0;h<=search.length-1;h++){
      storedWord = userS[n];
      temp = storedWord.substring(0,search.length-1);
      if(search === temp){
        possiblePeople++;
        console.log("something");
        if(possiblePeople == 1){
          //show up to the 1st element
          potential1 = userS[n];
          updateSearchBar();
        }else if(possiblePeople == 2){
          //show up to the 2nd element
          potential2 = userS[n];
          updateSearchBar();
        }else if(possiblePeople == 3){
          //show up to the 3rd element
          potential3 = userS[n];
          updateSearchBar();
        }else if(possiblePeople == 4){
          //show up to the 4th element
          potential4 = userS[n];
          updateSearchBar();
        }else if(possiblePeople == 5){
          //show up to the 5th element
          potential5 = userS[n];
          updateSearchBar();
        }else if(possiblePeople > 5){
          break;
        }
      }else{
        console.log("Nothing");
        //hide everything
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I've tried altering the for loops to where userS[n] is defined before the var h loop, and ive tried altering the if statement to detect the same value in different ways (i.e. putting search and temp in a String(), having search test if its equal to a substring of storedWord, having an extra if statement inside and having it loop through each individual character in the search) but nothing works and I have no idea why.

Comment: Please console log right after userS = getColumn("User's Data","name").  Console log right after storedWord = userS[n].  And again after temp = storedWord.substring(0,search.length-1).  Compare the 3, what do you get?

Comment: I did that and it was the stupidest thing. I had to make that bottom else statement to be conditional on possiblePeople == 0. so stupid. Cant believe I didn't think of that. Thank you!!